# What should we use between type or interface?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript to create some application and I don't know what should I use between the type or the interface/class when declaring variable or methods.

Example of Type :

```
public equals(rect: Rectangle): boolean {
    return (this.x === rect.x && this.y === rect.y && this.width === rect.width && this.height === rect.height);
}
```

Example of Interface/Class :

```
public equals(rect: Rectangle): Boolean {
    return (this.x === rect.x && this.y === rect.y && this.width === rect.width && this.height === rect.height);
    }
```

Is there a better way between this two solutions ? And why should we use one over another ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost always use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.

The lower-case versions `boolean`, `number`, and `string` refer to the JavaScript primitive types of the same name. These are the types you get from normal expressions like `true`, `1 + 1`, or `"hello"`.

The upper-case versions `Boolean`, `Number`, and `String` refer to the `object` versions of those same types. You only get objects like this if you try hard, e.g. by calling `new String('hello')`. These objects *mostly* behave like their primitive counterparts, but have slightly different behavior (e.g. `typeof (new String('hello'))` is "`object`", not `"string"`. Basically, just avoid thinking about these unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

*Boolean* is a wrapper object. For instance, you could write:

```
var b = new Boolean('true');
```

*boolean* is one of the three primitive types of JavaScript. In this case, you should use *boolean*. *Boolean* has very few use cases, but that's a different post.

This issue will generally only come up when dealing with primitives: *boolean*, *string* and *number*. As with *boolean*, always use the lowercase version, as it represents the primitive type and not it's wrapper.